# VSCode typescript ctrl+shift+b works fine, but after editing intellisence cant find symbols

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am having problems with typescript intelligence in vscode. I have the project building fine with `tsconfig.json` and `.vscode/tasks.json` but as soon as i edit a file I get red lines under anything that isnt defined in the specific file. Is there a way to point the incremental/automatic compiler to my tsconfig.json ?

edit: I can get around this problem by using explicit `/// <reference`s in my files, but i would rather it looked at the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: have you tried running tsc -w in your project folder?

Comment: hey @toskv , just tried that and it seems to recompile fine without the references there... not sure why vscode is having issues

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you send "-w" as an argument.

For example:

```js
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // args is the watch argument 
    "args": ["-w"],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Keep in mind though, VS Code will highlight issues with your code either way. Unless you have a more complex setup I would say that's enough.